# Duplicated content - how to tell Google I am original author

Tags: seo, google, duplicate-content

Let's say I prepared an article I wish to publish on my not so popular blog. But I am afraid that this article is so good that much more popular site will steal it and publish it on its own. I am guessing that because of low popularity of my blog, the Google would show links to the bad site instead of my own. Is there a way to prevent such outcome? What if I would prepare an article, publish it on my blog and *later* decide it it so good that I'll put it on Wikipedia, is there a way that Google would consider me above Wikipedia?

Comment: See questions under the [syndication](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syndication) tag for similar information. [This](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/48443/23812) is a good example to start.

Comment: As a matter of CYA, print your article and mail it to yourself. Do not post it until you get the article back. Do not open the envelope - EVER. Just file it away in a safe place (that you will actually remember). This is your proof of authorship. It is a very very old copyright trick. Do this just in case you ever need it.

Comment: One way is to make sure that you post the content on your site first and make sure it appears in the Google index for a period before posting it anywhere else. However, duplicate content should be avoided. So I would not post it again where you do not have complete control. Otherwise, you can get into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer:**

Use rich snippets to markup the article. Add the proper linking to the article in your sitemap. submit/resubmit the sitemap to Google via webmaster tools. Ping the sitemap to google/yahoo/bing. You can choose to publish the article via prweb or other syndication sources so a publication date associated to you is already in the global www record. The best tool you have to establish yourself as originating source to the web is have multiple sources reflect your article and publication/citation date earlier than potential content scrapers or plagiarizers. Article publication and schema is the public facing efforts to do this, the sitemap distribution is the behind the scenes effort to basically create a time stamp record if needed in the future.

On a side note, you cannot prevent plagiarism only take steps to minimize it or overcome it if it happens. Hope this gives you good answers.

Regarding the new comment added by the OP:

1.) Google is an aggregator and doesn't use authorship as a determining factor in SERP's or anything else. Use of Schema markup may improve SERP's only in so far as Google having a better understanding of the contents structure and intentions over other sources lacking proper markup. Otherwise, the issue of "copyright","content creator" and other similar claims falls on the shoulders of a court system, arbitration or just person to person contact and resolution between the claimant and the supposed offenders (plagiarizers or websites lacking proper citation of source).

See: [SearchEngineLand Article](http://searchengineland.com/google-authorship-dead-author-rank-202254) & [John Mueller - Post](https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/HZf3KDP1Dm8) & [Google Help - Authorship](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=en)

In so far as forcing any company/person/organization to acknowledge or respect your authorship claims, other than the phone call/email request for them to do so, your only other recourse is legal action in the courts to enforce [U.S. Copyright Law](http://copyright.gov) probably under the DMCA (Digital Millennium Copyright Act)

Comment: But if BigBadCompany does the same, relatively fast after you publish it, this won't work at all :)

Comment: Not true, the purpose of updating sitemap, ping sitemap and publish via syndicate source is that EVERYTHING is date/timestamped that goes into Google and the other search engines, as well as the syndication sources (PRWEB or others) - so long as you are the first to publish and push the data/information to the various sources your exposing it too, then IF bigbadcompany plagiarized it you have the means of showing your publication date/time precedes theres. Thus you are the original source.

Comment: Also, even though its no longer REQUIRED by US law, you can still place a copyright notice/mark onto the content. Thus if they plagiarizer it, you have a means of proper legal threat/action to force them to remove it or properly cite you as author.

Comment: Fine: BigBadCompany does exactly the same, but change their timestap to a little earlier than yours.

Comment: Ok, the OP asked how to tell Google. I told him how to tell Google within a few minutes of him making his content live to web.  I think your over complicating the issue. Do you have an answer to the OP? If so, post it.

Comment: It seems I am able to request Google to index single page from GWT. But the problem is not only about letting Google know about my page, but also about making it respect that I am original author.

Comment: so "first come, first served"?

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you put your article on Wikipedia you will link back to your original article as a source. (Wikipedia requires sources) Google is not likely to rank your site higher than Wikipedia, but you might find it in addition to the Wikipedia article when searching for it. In addition, your own site will likely be raised in ranking due to the fact that it is linked as a source in Wikipedia.

Also of note is that if your original article is used as a source that means it is credited with being an original.

Comment: Wikipedia requires references to source materials, not to article which aggregates such sources. I mean in case I described, my article would have sources, but I doubt it would be allowed to be considered source on Wiki.

Comment: Your site/page can be a Wikipedia source... potentially. Sources are not limited to putting if that is what you mean. Otherwise, it isn't likely that your content will be copy pasted into Wikipedia, but it will still be likely to contain relevant search terms and should show up on many similar searches...potentially. we are talking about the super secret and ever changing Google search engine, so...