# Prove to Yahoo and Bing that you are the original author

Tags: duplicate-content, bing, yahoo, yandex

Yandex (the main Russian search engine) has a form where you can submit text here:
https://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/authored-texts/owners.xml

If the text does not exist already, then yandex will treat this text as if it belongs to you.
Our website, which produces weekly original content regularly uses this service.

How do you achieve the same thing in Yahoo and Bing?  ([Google is covered here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72617/duplicated-content-how-to-tell-google-i-am-original-author))

P.S. It does not need to appear at the top of SERPs, as long as the system somehow knows the author.

Answer (score 3):

Google and Bing do not have a function such as Yandex to tell them what is the original source of the content. Google will generally go on the first version that was indexed and Bing is possibly the same.

Google can get it wrong though, so if you see sites out ranking yours with your content, you can file a DMCA take down request:  [Digital Millennium Copyright Act](https://support.google.com/legal/answer/1120734.)

If it's a site that has just scraped your content, you can report it via here [Scraper Report](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Pw1KVOVRyr4a7ezj_6SHghnX1Y6bp1SOVmy60QjkF0Y/viewform)

There is a video form Google about this subject here: [How can I make sure that Google knows my content is original?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LsB19wTt0Q)

Comment: The approach of having someone copy and then trying hard to remove it is fatally flawed, first off, an author can't possible see as many articles as a search engine does, so it should be the search engine telling the author that their content is being copied, so I guess twitter and "fetch as search engine" tools will have to suffice. All in all this seems like a really poor implementation by google, bing and yahoo

Answer (score -2):

Bing asks that you upload a file to your site with a certain filename

eg. bing45843738722.html

The content of the file is not important

Comment: I thought that file was for site verification for Bing Webmaster Tools.   I don't see how it helps Bing determine which site published data first.